# How to know the locator of post UI elements for Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am working on a project but it has the same feature as like sharing the post and then editing/deleting the same post, But the issue right now I am facing is that I don't know the locator of that post so that I can edit/delete after sharing that particular post.
Please help me all.

Facebook is the best example for this.

Comment: Please add some snippet of the post by inspecting.

Comment: I didn't got you sir,

Comment: How can we know the locators of element that are not visible or will be visible after posting the post on a website, Facebook is the best example, we share post but after that how can we locate them #Selenium?

This is question, if you want me to ask again, I didn't get you sir

Comment: Right click the post and select inspect. Or try using Mozilla developer browser you an inspect dynamic elements that appear on mouse hover.

Comment: the question is too broad, and I find it similar to 'how do you code?' type of question